# PHP script processing Paypal IPN payments stopped working

Tags: php, paypal-ipn

Two weeks ago my IPN payments processing PHP script triggered a 503 error and PayPal send an email I have to fix my script. As I didn't touch it for a long, long while I was wondering would went wrong.

I started debuging and at first there where no errors whatsoever, but then I also got 503 errors. I contacted the support team. They gave the default answers like use the `trim` function and `curl`. I even updated my code to their newest [example solution](https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples/blob/master/paypal_ipn.php) (which is missing the use of the `trim` function).

So what's wrong? Why is the script working only occasionally?

NOTE: I know, that the questions is not very precise, but I hope it contains enough key words as I ask it for documentary reasons as I will answer it myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason was rather obvious. It had to do something with my server. I use [Strato](http://www.strato.de), a professional company so I didn't suspect them at first, but a google for *503 strato* led to [the solution](http://www.wpupdate.de/strato-und-der-503-error). It is a security feature at Strato which can be turned off, but is on by default. I really wonder, why it didn't fire earlier, but this is how you can turn it off.

- log into your account
- choose your package
- go to *Security* (*Sicherheit*) in the menu
- choose *ServerSide Security*
- turn off *Filter agains guestbook spam* (*Filter gegen Gästebuch Spam*)

I hope this saves some of you the trouble of going through your scripts. Try this first if you have 503 errors.

Comment: Thank you for the update, it probably will help someone down the road. Please remember to choose this as the correct answer when time limit permits.